# Best practice for "hidden" JavaScript HTTP request?

Tags: javascript, flash, http, html, xmlhttprequest

I'm not exactly sure how to formulate the question, but I think it's more of a suggestions request, instead of a question per se.

We are building an HTML5 service on which users get credited (rewarded, on social gaming lingo) for completing a series of offers. Most of these offers are video ad watching. We already have an implementation of this built on Flash, but for HTML5 I'm encountering a bit more issues on how to make the request calls to validate legit watched video ads. On the Flash interface, we have a series of HTTP requests that the SWF makes, some upon the video playback starts, in the middle and at the end, each one of those requests are related to each other, meaning, the response of one is needed on the next request, etc. Most of the logic to "hide" this "algorithm" is lightly hidden on the SWF binary, and it pretty much serves it purpose.

However, for HTML5 we have to rely on world visible JavaScript and that "hidden" logic is open wide. So, I guess this is a call for suggestions on how these cases are usually handled so that an skilled person could not (so easily) get access to it and exploit the service to get credited programmatically. Obfuscating the JavaScript seems like something that could help but that in no way protects fully.

There's of course some extra security on the backend (like frequency capping, per user capping, etc), but since our capping clears every day, an skilled person could still find a way to get credit for all available offers even without completing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to ensure that your server can distinguish requests that happened as the result of the user interacting with your UI in ways you approve of from requests that did not happen that way.

There are a number of points of attack on such a system.

1. Inspect the JavaScript to find the event handler and invoke them via Firebug or another tool.
2. Inspect  any keys from your code, and generate the HTTP requests without involving the browser.
3. Run code in the browser to programmatically generate events.
4. Use a 3rd-party tool that instruments the browser to generate clicks.

If you've got reasonable solutions to instrumentation attacks (3 and 4), then you can look at [Is there any way to hide javascript functions from end user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862518/is-there-any-way-to-hide-javascript-functions-from-end-user/5869959#5869959) for ways to get secrets into the client to allow you to sign your requests.  Beyond that, obfuscation is the only (and imperfect) way to stop a not-too-determined attacker from any exploitation, and rate-limiting and UI event logging are probably your best bets for stopping determined attackers from benefiting from wide-scale fraud.

Comment: I would add 5. Inspecting http traffic, and forging http requests once you know what they look like.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to prevent a determined attacker (even with SWF, though it's more obfuscated). Your best bet is to make sure that:

1. Circumventing your measures is expensive in terms of effort, perhaps by using a computationally expensive crypto algorithm so they can't just set up a bunch of scripts to do it.
2. The payoff is minimal (user-capping is an example of how to reduce payoff; if you're giving out points, it's fine; if you're mailing out twenty dollar bills, you're out of luck)

Cost-benefit.